# "Warning: Unreachable code" in solidity when overriding a function to make it fail and that is used elsewhere

Tags: solidity, compilation, function-override, warnings

I have the following code sample

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

error MyError();

abstract contract A
{
    function f1() public pure virtual returns(bool);
    function f2() public pure virtual returns(bool)
    {
        bool result = f1();
        return result;
    }
}
contract B is A
{
    function f1() public pure override returns (bool)
    {
        revert MyError();
    }
}
contract C is A
{
    function f1() public pure override returns (bool)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and when I do compile it, I get the following warning (which is quite blocking for us as it blocks our whole deployment process)

**Warning: Unreachable code.**

**--> contracts/test/SolidityTest.sol:12:9:**

**|         return result;**

**|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^**

I even tried to override both functions like this, but got the same issue :

```
contract B is A
{
    function f1() public pure override returns (bool)
    {
        revert MyError();
    }
    function f2() public pure override returns (bool)
    {
        revert MyError();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance if you know any ways of making it compile nicely

Answer (score 0):

The warning is correct. In contract B, the return statement will never be reached. A revert statement stops execution of a transaction and reverts the entire execution. If this is the desired effect for contract B, ignore the warning.

Comment: Thank you Ammon! Indeed, that is what I understood as well. This is why I did the second implementation of contract B that overrides both functions. In my mind, that should have solved the problem as both underlying functions are not called anymore but not (this is cannot figure out why)...
To let you know, I'm now trying to ignore the warning using hardhat-ignore-warnings but cannot make it work... (cause yes, it is the desired effect as we want to prevent some usecases in some specific implementations...)